# Match first n elements where n is matched before

Tags: pattern-matching

Can we use a matched integer to determine how many elements in a sequence should be matched?

In other words, do you think it is possible to generalize `foo` for any n?

```
isM = MemberQ[{m1, m2, m3, m4}, #] &;
foo[expr_] := expr /.
  {
   F[_, n_?(# == 2 &)][_?isM, _?isM, ___] :> 0,
   F[_, n_?(# == 3 &)][a_, b_, c_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c}, _?isM] >= 2,
   F[_, n_?(# == 4 &)][a_, b_, c_, d_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c, d}, _?isM] >= 2,
   F[_, n_?(# == 5 &)][a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c, d, e}, _?isM] >= 2,
   F[_, n_?(# == 6 &)][a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, _?isM] >= 2,
   F[_, n_?(# == 7 &)][a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, _?isM] >= 2,
   F[_, n_?(# == 8 &)][a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, ___] :> 
    0 /; Count[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, _?isM] >= 2
   }
```

> F[a, 3][m2, x, m3, y, z] (*should be matched, i.e. =0*)

> F[a, 3][m2, x, y, m3, z] (*should not match*)

Comment: Might want to use the 2-arg form of `Repeated` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a happy thought right after posting. In my case I can just match all arguments [a,b,c,d,...] and select the first n arguments for the condition.

```
foo[expr_] := 
 expr /. F[_, n_?(# >= 2 &)][ind___] :> 
   0 /; Count[(List@ind)[[1 ;; n]], _?isM] >= 2
```